# Furniture as a general term for curtain accessories

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

Can the word "furniture" be used as a general term for accessories and fittings, for example, curtain accessories (hooks, brackets, rings)?

> Furniture: the small accessories or fittings that are required for a
>   particular task or function ([source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/furniture))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have pointed to is a definition that explains how to
*understand* a word when it is used in a certain way,
but not when you can *use* the word in that way.

The term "furniture" has a well-known technical meaning in printing,
for example. It means certain pieces that are fit among or around the
pieces of movable type in an old-style printing press.
But I think one would not use "furniture" to refer to other small accessories
or fittings (such as a composing stick) that are used to assemble the type
or operate the press.

If you search the Web for "rifle furniture," you may find a
number of links to manufacturers or sellers advertising certain parts of
rifles. (The word seems to correspond to the stock of a rifle or
parts that serve the function of the stock.)
A rifle has other accessory parts (such as sights) that appear
not to be "furniture."

A Web search for "Mac furniture" is not as successful. 
That usage may have been intended to work by analogy, 
comparing the assignment of functions of graphical objects
in  software interface to the placement of pieces of 
furniture within a room.

So the question is whether "furniture" would correctly be 
understood when used to denote things such as curtain hooks.
Unless you have observed multiple uses of the word in that way
by people whose business it is to deal with such things as
curtain hooks and rods, I would not advise
taking the risk of using it that way.
The risk of misunderstanding is large, since
you mean to speak of things that are part of the
general furnishings of a room
but are not among the things most people would think of as *furniture.*

Answer (score 9):

In the home, *furniture* means items like tables, chairs, beds, wardrobes, etc. A more generic term is [*furnishings*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/furnishings). Curtains and cushions, etc, are called *soft furnishings*. Sewing accessories are sometimes called [*notions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notions_(sewing)) by hobbyists, but it isn't a well-known usage.

> **furnishings** noun [plural]
>   ​
>   the furniture, curtains, and other decorations in a room or building:
>
> - Bathroom furnishings are in the basement of the store.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: I wouldn't say "furnishings" could be used for specifically the accessories to curtains (hooks, etc.) as stated in OP. Though I'm afraid I can't think of a way to specify it. The term "fixings and fittings" (or just one or the other) is probably what I'd use.

Comment: You're right. I lost sight of the question, there.

Answer (score 6):

The general term for those things, among people who sell and install curtains, etc. , is 'hardware'.  When you move from one home to another, you would say:

> All the hardware for the living room curtains is in that box.

When you buy new curtains, you would ask:

> Will my existing hardware work, or do I need to buy new stuff?

When you paint a room, you would say:

> I'll have all the hardware down off the walls tomorrow morning.

[Hardware](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hardware) (MW, definitions 1 and 2)

> ware (as fittings, cutlery, tools, utensils, or parts of machines) made of metal
>
> major items of equipment or their components used for a particular purpose

That's the specific sense of the word.  What's confusing about it is that a 'hardware store' sells a lot more than just hardware, including lumber, plumbing supplies, furniture, appliances, etc.  Some someone who is not an interior designer, carpenter, builder, or painter might refer to a piece of lumber as 'hardware', since they bought it at a 'hardware store'.

Some people also refer to those pieces as 'fixtures'.

[Fixture](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fixture) (MW definition 2a)

> something that is fixed or attached (as to a building) as a permanent appendage or as a structural part

Comment: http://thomasbelmont.com/home-accessories/curtain-furniture

Comment: Maybe __curtain furniture__ is a British English idiom, however, in the US, __curtain hardware__ is much more prevalent.  See [here](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Decor-Blinds-Window-Treatments-Curtain-Rods-Hardware/N-5yc1vZasco) and [here](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/category/home-decor/curtain-rods-hardware/10552/).

Answer (score 4):

The word *furniture* cannot be used for all accessories and fittings but can be used for some.

The source you provided gives an example of rifle fittings (rifle furniture) and I would give an example of door handles, locks and hinges, referred to as door furniture.

There is also street furniture such as street lighting, signs, benches and litter bins

Comment: Good, but you don't currently answer the specific question as to whether furniture can be used for "curtain accessories (hooks, brackets, rings)", i.e. would "curtain furniture" be widely understood. I suggest not.

Comment: @AndyT: Chris answered my initial question about sewing accessories. I have altered my question then.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use "furniture" as a general term for any accessories or fittings. household furniture like sofa, table, chairs, book shelves this kind of product referred as furniture.
If you are still confused check out this Wikipedia article *[FURNITURE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furniture)*